# How to ask professor to post more example?

Tags: professorship, email, communication, grading, homework

My professor always posts solved problems on the course website but for the last chapter, he did not post any solved problems. Although we have our textbook, I think solved problems help me understand the chapters better. But now I could not understand the last chapter deeply, and I have difficulties to do assignments.

Could I ask him to post one or two solved problems? If yes, how should I ask?

Comment: It is almost always proper to ask. It is possible that there is no time for him to do it, but asking is a good thing. I hope he also gives you a lot of _unsolved_ problems as well.

Comment: why unsolved problems?

Comment: Because you learn better by solving problems with the material, not by reading solutions. Work is what changes your brain. Learning is an active sport, not a spectator sport.

Comment: @Buffy - learning is a _contact_ sport! You have to grapple with the problem, not just walk around with it!

Comment: @JonCuster, maybe I'll disagree. Tai Chi isn't a contact sport, but a saying is that you need 10,000 repetitions of a move to truly learn and understand it. But I won't _fight_ with you over it. ;)

Comment: As this is the final chapter, perhaps the prof has deliberately not provided problems for you all to hone your own skills that you have been developing up to this point.

Comment: @buffy But students also learn better when they have concrete examples of exactly what the instructor expects, rather than waiting for feedback.  Seeing a solved problem isn't useful for learning to solve that _specific problem_, but it can be very useful for learning to solve that _kind of problem_.

Comment: @JeffE, again, only if you practice. Learning comes from practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as simple as you explained the problem in the question. start by explaining how his solved examples helped you understand X and Y ( e specific as much as you can). Then ask for solved example related to Z ( again be specific ) end with simple show of appreciation.

Good Luck!